# Which Android/iPhone Cross Platform Framework for 2015?

Tags: android, ios, sencha-touch, titanium, phonegap-plugins

Three years ago I explored the option of using PhoneGap for one of my app developments. I found it extremely hard at the time to integrate with Facebook and connect to the camera and read a barcode. I ended up giving up and writing the app natively - and don't regret it.

But three years are past and I am wondering if I should be looking at this possibility again. I need JSON communications with my backend, facebook integration, swipeable cards (like tinder) and internal persistence.

I've noticed that the big players currently are:

- Sencha
- PhoneGap
- Appcelerator Titanium
- Corona
- Xamarin

Did I forget any?

So, is anyone using any of the frameworks I've mentioned below and could tell me how mature they are these days?

Thank you

Comment: Ionic is also a good option.http://ionicframework.com/

Comment: Ionic looks interesting indeed

Comment: Appcelerator Titanium! Don't know how to make a swipeable cards, but its JavaScript and native.
For facebook, JSON and internal persistence, thats the best \o/

Answer (score 2):

I am biased towards Appcelerator Titanium because I've been using it for years, however, I would still highly recommend it.

PhoneGap, Sencha and Corona basically all are website wrappers for your mobile phone. They do offer API support for stuff like camera, but it will still be HTML. HTML on a phone will always run slower than native implementation. Although you might not always notice it as a user, as a developer you need to spend a LOT of time optimizing so users will not notice it.

Xamarin I do not have experience with, but I heard is is basically Titanium, but a smaller community and much more expensive. I would consider that a no-go as opposed to Titanium.

So, I would recommend Titanium. But even though you build the app in JavaScript/XML it still will be compiled to use the Native API's, and the UI is actually native code manipulated by JavaScript in the backend. All UI interactions and building of UI will happen on native ground and will be much quicker.

Another alternative you haven't mentioned is React Native. Also in the same space as Titanium and Xamarin, but I personally do not really like the code structure for it. Titanium (by using Alloy, not classic) is pretty solid, and MVC.

Comment: I didn't know TItanium was build the app natively. I thought it was an HTTP wrapper just like PhoneGap. That is quite interesting! I will have a look on it for sure!

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to check out the following slideshow:

http://www.slideshare.net/joshcjensen/connectjs-2015-building-native-mobile-applications-with-javascript

It gives you a good overview about Titanium, Native Script and React Native.

And its good to know, that Appcelerator is creating "Hyperloop" (demo code: https://speakerdeck.com/fokkezb/titanium-develop-native-mobile-apps-with-javascript?slide=19 ) and there is a preview already. That allows you to use native code in Javascript without creating external modules and gives you even more system access.(use xcode projects inside your app, use CocoaPods, ...)

Comment: miga, I really was not aware of Native Script and React Native. Very interesting. Is there any that you recommend? I have read the power point you've recommended and it seems like Titanium is the most stable solution. But React Native is free, so I am very interest in that one :)

Comment: Titanium is free as well (https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile) and has a very good MVC structure like @rene-pot was saying. I'm using titanium on a daily basis so I'm biased, too :) If I'm correct titanium is the only one that will encrypt the js inside the app which is an advantage. And the documentation and community is very good! But have a look at the frameworks yourself and decide which one is best for you (syntax, documentation, ease of use). At the end they all produce an app :)

Comment: miga thanks a lot mate. Titanium is free, but the project needs to be open source, does it? You have to have the project open in github? I'll go with Titanium though. Seems like the safest bet. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Sencha** is really good Framework to make cross plateform web mobile and native application. You can go with this but before gone through you should read about this.

https://www.sencha.com/

https://www.sencha.com/business-web-applications-why-sencha/#developers

Answer (score 1):

Intel’s Multi-OS Engine is a technology that enables developers using their Java expertise to develop native mobile applications for iOS and Android on Windows and/or OS X development host machines without compromising the native look, feel and performance. This technology is a stand-alone plug-in that can be integrated into Android Studio.
It's free and let's you write code and create UI easily in Android Studio. You can generate API for 3rd party libraries in Java etc.
More details and the download link are here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/multi-os-engine

One more tool it called XDK. The Intel XDK cross-platform development environment enables software developers to develop, test, preview and deploy HTML5 web and hybrid apps: https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-xdk